# What is quantum mysticism?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Most of my questions on stack physics exchange are being commented on as being quantum mystic.
The questions I ask are basically related to [device independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device-independent_quantum_cryptography)  and how local hidden variable theory can't explain quantum mechanics ( by studying the violation of Bell inequalities, in relation to the paper [device independent outlook on quantum mechanics](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.3081) ). I read a little bit about quantum mysticism  on wikipedia but I don't find a relation to how 
device independent outlook on quantum mechanics is mystic , maybe I am missing something.
What exactly is [quantum mysticism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mysticism)?

Comment: I think this is off-topic here, but insofar as it asks about responses to your questions it may be worth asking in the [Physics Meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JohnRennie Will do so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about quantum mysticism, which is not physics. In so far as individual comments on your questions are concerned, ask the people *making* those comments.

Comment: @ACuriousMind sorry I just took the comments a bit personally I think. Anyways I can't delete as an answer is posted but I voted to close.

Comment: Quantum Mysticism is anything which must be resolutely ignored if we are not to face the fact that the whole foundation and fabric of reality is without foundation (and perhaps also without fabric) :-). A lot of the attempts to look at such areas are more hand waving than physics, but ultimately all such attempts to understand underlying precepts must be what Rutherford termed "Stamp Collecting". Rutherford exempted Physics alone from stamp collecting, but he had no basis for doing so :-). | I'm aware that this "answer" will satisfy nobody :-).

Comment: The question of where the boderline lies between mainstream physics and "quantum mysticism" is something I consider very much on topic

Comment: Well I've enjoyed some of your questions; don't know which ones were criticized but for me the ones I've seen certainly show a capacity to think deeply and ask worthwhile physics questions. Sometimes we all ask questions that may seem stupid to others, and to ourselves after we ask them, but their asking is nonetheless necessary to our learning.

Comment: @sasha: I guess it's mostly one user who likes to say your questions are quantum mysticism, and this is a user with very strong opinions. I have pointed out several times that in general, the question of device-independent quantum mechanics is not "mystic". The "problem" is that you ask questions relating to areas of "foundations of quantum mechanics", a field with a lot of debate and a lot of very questionable ideas.

Comment: The "problem" is that many people (maybe rightfully) consider the field of foundations of (nonrelativistic) qm to be purely philosophical at best. So, when you ask about these issues, you will get people that will tell you that the question is irrelevant for physics, just as you would if you ask about interpretations of quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the misapplication of QM to problems that may or may not benefit from such application, but which produces no experimentally testable theory. In many cases not even a mathematical model is produced, but "all is handwaving explanation and no proof".

Comment: What's an example for quantum mysticism with an associated mathematical model that however isn't experimentally testable? And what must be experimentally testable about it? The problem I have with coming up with some is that those theories which are almost trivially false don't fall in that regime, as they are experimentally testable.

Comment: The most borderline work has to be that of Penrose and Hameroff https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestrated_objective_reduction

Comment: As for "mysticism" with associated model, subjectively verifiable but not objectively, Quantum Suicide